# jQuery - Couldn't get the height of the header which is loaded from another file using load() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery. Actually i want to get the height of my header which is coming from some other file. I have used load() method to display my header. I tried some code to get the height. But that didn't work out.
So getting the height is possible here? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your header has an id attribute of `myHeader`:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html");
    setTimeout(function(){
        var height = $('#myHeader').height();
        alert(height);
    },200);
```

Comment: Thank you :) Can you please tell me how to use this height outside the function?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I would say use setTimeout just to be sure that the div has rendered before getting its properties.

Comment: Using `setTimeout` isn't the correct solution to do this.

Comment: It works, Thank you. But i'm wondering why we use setTimeout() and how it works, if we use that.

Comment: @prabu dont use `setTimeout`, its bad code writing. `setTimeout` isn't meant for use cases like the one you described.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *callback* function provided by the `.load` method. This function is meant for handling code after the request has completed.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/header.html", function() {
    var height = $('header').height();
    console.log(height);
});
```

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is
>   fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set
>   to each DOM element in turn.
>
> http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function

---

As noted in the comments, you want to use the `height` *variable* outside the function. As solution to this you could create a function which you pass to the callback function.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/header.html", function() {
    var height = $('header').height();

    // Call function
    do_something_with_header( height );
});

// Call this function in your load callback
function do_something_with_header( height ) {
    console.log( height );
}
```

Comment: Prabu wanted a way to do this outside the callback function.

Comment: I posted an answer exactly like yours before. I had to update it.

Comment: Yes i want to use the height outside the function. Keeping that height i want to do some other stuff.

Comment: @prabu but with the settimeout function you still wont be able to use the height directly after the function. As the variable isnt created yet. What if the request takes 600ms? Then your whole code will fail. You will run into problems with the current solution, maybe not today .. but next week.

Comment: @Red - Yes you are right. Then how can i use the height out side the function? Can you give me a example please? So that i can understand easily.

Comment: You don't need it outside the function, as you could just put all the code inside the `do_something_with_header` function. Or seperate it into different functions.

Answer (score 0):

make a global variable and assign to use out side function